# How to set line height to text box in RDLC report?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have tried to increase line height to text box in RDLC report. I have increased values of padding and line spacing properties. But padding and line-height properties not working in RDLC report. How to resolve that above mentioned issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of, the line-height property is only supported when using the HTML markup.
Just set the TextBox (or Placeholder) markup type as `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as style"`. Then you can simply use CSS to format your text as wanted.

For your example you could use an expression similar to this:

```
= "<p style='line-height:1.5;'>" + Fields!MyText.Value + "</p>"
```

---

**Update:** The above code is for when you're defining the expression in the Designer view. I'll add the code after compilation to avoid any mistakes for those that wish to edit it in the code:

```
<Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
                <Value>="&lt;p style='line-height:1.5'&gt;" &amp; Fields!MyText.Value &amp; "&lt;/p&gt;"</Value>
                <MarkupType>HTML</MarkupType>
                <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
            </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <Style />
    </Paragraph>
</Paragraphs>
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply line-height for table header? Expression is available only for data.

Comment: When I use span tag instead of p tag, line-height property not working. Also when I try to reduce line-height value for p tag, there is no changes in design.

Comment: It is possible that this is not visible in the ReportDesigner but it should definitely be applied when exporting to PDF or in the ReportViewer if you set the display mode to printlayout. `SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)`

Comment: The printlayout display mode will be applicable when exporting to Excel?

Comment: If you did it correctly, then yes. I've updated the answer slightly to clear up possible confusion. You should only use `<` and `>` when working in the designer, else you'll have to use `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Comment: Sorry to bump into this but I am currently facing the same problem and `"<p style='line-height:1.5;'>"` is not working for me. If anyone can help then please check my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869417/rdlc-textbox-line-height-line-spacing

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextBox (or Placeholder) markup type as HTML - Interpret HTML tags as style"> In the expression :

```css
="<div style='padding-bottom:0.05in;'>" & Fields!Description.Value & "</div>"
```